# Vsto Problem Can't Access Name Range Name Property

Tags: c#, excel, vb.net, vsto

I am Creating Document Level Addin for Excel, I have NameRange "testNameRange" in Excel sheet, So I can access its value with `Globals.SettingsSheet.testNameRange.Value` This is working but I don't have access to its Name `Globals.SettingsSheet.testNameRange.Name` Should Give me "testNameRange" String.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't have access to"? Does it throw an error? Do you get a name that you didn't expect?

Comment: No, it is giving me System.__ComObject, I need access to Name Of NameRange to Know which is which, Currently I am using nameof(object) method to get name of variable which is same is name of NameRange. `Debug.Print(nameof(Globals.Sheet1.test).ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

You can cast it to the [Name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.name) class. Each `Name` object represents a defined name for a range of cells. `Names` can be either built-in names—such as Database, Print_Area, and Auto_Open—or custom names.

The `Name` object is a member of the `Names` collection for the `Application`, `Workbook`, and `Worksheet` objects. Use `Names(index)`, where `index` is the name index number or defined name, to return a single `Name` object.